# Blazor server app or angular when working with JWT

Tags: c#, html, angular, jwt, blazor

Hi i am developping new web application and this application using jwt authentification (token and refreshtoken)
at first i decide to create website with blazor framework because my server side devlopped with .net core
but now i found so many problem with jwt authentification in blazor server app Ifound that is should always use IJSRuntime and i think that will be a big problem in future especialy the performence of my web application
**i'm now confused about continue my work with blazor or going to angular please help me .**

Comment: _"blazor server app"_  Do you not have a WebAssembly project?   Blazor Server would be a little awkward with JWT.

Comment: _"especialy the performence"_  - that will not be an issue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman change it to WebAssembly project will be a good soulution ?

Comment: Do a test-drive with the template app: Blazor WebAssembley + Hosted + Individual Users.

Answer (score 0):

For me this decision was always more that technology I was more used to. I use more C# than Java Script so it was simpler for me to use Blazor for the fronend than a java script based framework.

Comment: You seem to imply that JavaScript has something to do with Java :)

Comment: I don't think so but angular is java script isn't it?

Comment: More Typescript than javascript but essentially yes. Oh you split the word javascript into java and script and it spans two lines. I thought you were referring to Java, sorry :)